# What is the cause of "can not create printer" when exporting to pdf

Tags: qgis, printing, pdf, windows-10

Sometimes I get the message (this is directly translated from Swedish) "Could not create printer" when I try to use Export to pdf in layout-window, when I check off the geopdf it works

What is wrong?

Comment: what operating system are you on?

Comment: win 10 64 bit QGIS-version 3.16.7-Hannover

Comment: I think the problem is big virtual layers in this project 5,3 GB tif ortofoto, without that it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is big virtual layers (in this project 5,3 GB tif ortofoto), without that it works